# AD7606 DAQ and datalogging

Tags: sensors, arduino-due, adc, datalogging, analog-sampling

I'm making a Data Acquisition System for force impact usign an AD7606 from Analog Devices, an Arduino DUE and a load cell. I already tested it following [this guide](https://www.hackster.io/mitov/connect-ad7606-8-channel-16-bit-adc-in-16-bit-parallel-mode-4a6cfc) an making the proper changes for Arduino DUE and some potentiometers for simulating the input signals. I can read variable 1-5 V signals pretty good but when I tried to read mV signals from my load cell I can't see any changes in the Visuino Scope. I've read some forums and using an amplifier is recommended. However, when I read the AD7606 datasheet it says that since it has a High Analog Input Impedance and Internal amplifiers, a previous  amplification phase isn't needed. Also, I want to avoid the noise from the external amplifiers.

I also tested my load cell using the HX711 ADC and it works fine, but I can't use it for my application because of its limited sampling frequency (80 Hz). AD7606 can give up to 200 kilo samples per second.

Does any one knows if I'm missing something for my input signal? if an amplifier is really nedded can you recommend me one?

Thanks

Comment: which load cell are you using and how is it connected?

Comment: It is a full Wheatstone Bridge made with 4 350 ohm straing gauges. 2 coils are fed.